# Fixing Armature Bone Rotations

Tags: animation, rigging, armature, bones, unreal-engine

What should i do with this? I want to prepeare him for animation, by putting ik and controllers. What is important for me to do in this situation and where to start?
Animation will be used in Unreal Engine
[image: Linked Picture]

Comment: Actually, you should manually rotate all bones aligned according to arms, legs, etc

Comment: Or add a new rig with Rigify add on. Watch [this](https://youtu.be/f2pTkW-1JkE)